# Measure acceleration for X mins

Tags: arduino, interrupts, accelerometer

I have a situation where I have to check if a body is motion or not for x minutes. If it is in motion for x minuteds then the function should return true, else it should return false.

I have an accelerometer which generates an interrupt as soon as it goes above a set threshold. Can someone please help me with the logic of writing this?

Comment: Accelerometer does not measure a constant speed motion, only accelerations.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply Eugene. Actually I don't want to measure speed. I just want to see if the body is vibrating or not for more than x mins

Comment: Then you better check if the system is "still" for a certain period of time by continuously sampling the accelerometer values and checking that they are within certain margins.

Comment: Then you're better off just constantly polling the accelerometer to see if there any readings that exceed a minimum threshold. And if there are no readings that do for long enough then consider it stopped. The accelerometer will not exceed the threshold the entire time it's vibrating so readings below the threshold don't necessarily mean it has stopped vibrating. I suppose you could rely on your interrupt and make sure the interrupt occurs often enough.

Comment: Great thanks for the help Eugene and DKNguyen.